# Unable to use fstream class to create a file in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am posting this question because I am unable to correctly implement get() and put() functions for file handling purposes in c++.. I have tried searching on Google for an answer which could resolve my queries, but still not able to find one..

Hence, I am posting the following code.. In the following code, I am opening a TEXT file for writing and then, the same file for reading purposes...

The program is not giving any syntactical errors but it is not performing as per my desired expectations..

Here is the complete code:

```
/*
 * IOOperationsonCharacters.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 13-Dec-2015
 *      Author: Suyash Dayal
 *   Objective: I/O Operations on Characters
 */

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char string[80];

    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin>>string;

    int len = strlen(string);

    fstream file;           // input and output stream
    cout<<"\nOpening the 'TEXT' file and storing the string in it.\n\n";

    file.open("TEXT", ios::in | ios::out);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        file.put(string[i]);    // put a character to file

    file.seekg(0);          // go to the start

    char ch;
    cout<<"Reading the file contents: ";
    while(file)
    {
        file.get(ch);       // get a character from file
        cout<<ch;           // display it on screen
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program takes the input of the string but does not create the file TEXT.. In fact, if I use ofstream class, it gives an syntactical error..

I am also attaching the output for your perusal..

> Enter a string: Suyash
>
> Opening the 'TEXT' file and storing the string in it.
>
> Reading the file contents:

Any kind of help will be much appreciated...

Comment: Here is a code that can help you with your file handling: http://ideone.com/z3HG1E

Comment: I am still learning c++ and am facing difficulty with file handling.. To be more precise, using put() &  get() and read() and write() functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In fact, if I use ofstream class, it gives an syntactical error..

Yes, because you cannot read anything from **output** stream.

In your case your problem in not handling all potential problems with file. Are you sure that file can be written before you write into it?

Check it after opening:

```
if(!file) {
    std::cerr << "File is not open\n"
    //...
}
```

Problem most likely lies in the fact that there is no file named *TEXT*. And it is required to exist for your chosen open mode. Read this for information on different modes and their behavior: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open

Comment: The first segment of the code is for writing the string into the file 'TEXT' and, if it doesn't exist, then, create it.. And, the second part was for reading from the file.. And, to see whether I was using fstream stream incorrectly, I made some changes in the code before running it with ofstream class.. But, thank you for the reference...

Comment: @Suyash Dayal: It will **not** create file if it does not exist. By providing `ios::in | ios::out` mode you explicitely said that non-existing file should be an error. If you want to create file if it does not exis, add  `ios::trunc` to the mix

Comment: Thanks for the tip... It works... And, I did know the file was not being created.. I guess, I phrased the question wrong..